# How can I implement a 3-layer NN to learn the x² function?

Tags: python, neural-network

We have to write a simple 3-layer NN that learn f(x)=x² with the softplus activation function at the end.

In my implementation the reults are just rubbish and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad
from autograd import elementwise_grad
from autograd import hessian
import random

class Neural_Net(object):
    def __init__(self, inputSize, hiddenSize, outputSize,
                 learning_rate=0.0001, epochs=100,
                 activation1="sigmoid", activation2="softplus"):
        self.inputSize = inputSize
        self.outputSize = outputSize
        self.hiddenSize = hiddenSize
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs

        if activation1 == 'softplus':
            self.activation1 = softplus
            self.activation1_grad = softplus_grad
        if activation1 == 'sigmoid':
            self.activation1 = sigmoid
            self.activation1_grad = sigmoid_grad
        if activation1 == 'tanh':
            self.activation1 = np.tanh
            self.activation1_grad = tanh_grad

        if activation2 == 'softplus':
            self.activation2 = softplus
            self.activation2_grad = softplus_grad
        if activation2 == 'sigmoid':
            self.activation2 = sigmoid
            self.activation2_grad = sigmoid_grad
        if activation2 == 'tanh':
            self.activation2 = np.tanh
            self.activation2_grad = tanh_grad

        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize)
        self.b1 = np.ones((1, self.hiddenSize))
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize)
        self.b2 = np.ones((1, self.outputSize))

    def forward_prop(self, X):    
        self.Z1 = np.dot(X, self.W1) + self.b1
        self.A1 = self.activation1(self.Z1)
        self.Z2 = np.dot(self.A1, self.W2) + self.b2
        self.A2 = self.activation2(self.Z2)

        return self.A2

    def back_prop(self, X, Y):
        self.dA2 = (self.A2 - Y)*self.activation2_grad(self.Z2)
        self.dA1 = (np.dot(self.dA2,self.W2.T))*self.activation1_grad(self.Z1)

        self.W1 -= self.learning_rate*X.T.dot(self.dA1)
        self.b1 -= self.learning_rate*self.dA1

        self.W2 -= self.learning_rate*np.dot(self.A1.T, self.dA2)
        self.b2 -= self.learning_rate*self.dA2

    def train(self, X, Y):
        self.forward_prop(X)
        self.back_prop(X, Y)

def softplus(x):
    return np.log(1 + np.exp(x))

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

softplus_grad = elementwise_grad(softplus)
sigmoid_grad = elementwise_grad(sigmoid)
tanh_grad = elementwise_grad(np.tanh)


NN1 = Neural_Net(inputSize=1, hiddenSize=1, outputSize=1, epochs=10000)
for epoch in range(NN1.epochs):
    X = np.array(([[random.randint(1, 100)]]))
    Y = np.square(X)
    A2 = NN1.forward_prop(X)
    print("Input: " + str(X))
    print("Actual Output: " + str(Y))
    print("Predicted Output: " + str(A2))
    print("Loss: " + str(np.mean(np.square(Y - A2))))
    print("\n")
    NN1.train(X, Y)
```

The expected output just increases and depending on which parameters I choose it becomes NaN or inf before it finishes

Answer (score 0):

Just like at forward step you calculate Z1 then A1 then Z2 then A2, at backward step you should calculate gradients at opposite order: dA2 then dZ2 then dA1 then dZ1.  You don't calculate dZ2 or dZ1, therefore it cannot work.  Maybe you have other problems as well, but this one is the most obvious.

To check that the gradients are correct, calculate them directly (for each weight or bias, increase it by a small value epsilon, see how much the error changed, divide by epsilon).  Such a direct calculation should be close to weight gradients.  You don't calculate them explicitly, but should for test purposes.

Comment: I implemented the 4 equations for backprop as stated in this article: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html. They only calculate the δ for each layer and use it to update the weights and biases. I thought that the derivaves for z are already in those equations

Comment: Anyways, do what I wrote in the second paragraph.

Comment: could you maybe elaborate on what you mean by calculate them directly? sorry, english is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

More problems:

if hiddensize=1, it means you have just one neuron in the middle. It is not enough to approximate x**2.

if the output activation is sigmoid, it can output only numbers from 0 to 1.  How do you output numbers from 1 to 100 squared?  `1**2=1, 2**2=4, ..., 100**2=10000`, while your output unit is only able to output numbers from 0 to 1.

Comment: sorry, I just changed the hiddenSize to 1 to work through the code without having too many numbers. I already tried it with more neurons.

the output activation is softplus, sigmoid is used as the activation in the hidden layer.

Comment: Sorry, i meant softplus. It cannot produce numbers outside [0,1] interval.  If you have softplus, your inputs should be from -1 to 1.